# Why are there 2 generated linker scripts by STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: gcc, build, linker, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm learning STM32 bare metal programming and in that quest I'm using STM32F429ZI mcu. I read a lot of examples on the internet and all of them use only one linker script. I'm thinking if these examples perfected for my MCU then the linker script will be the same as one(s) that is generated by STM32CubeIDE in term of functionality (?).

Now here my question, when I generated my project using STM32CubeIDE I got 2 linker scripts, `STM32F429ZITX_FLASH.ld` and `STM32F429ZITX_RAM.ld` but *when I checked the build log* only one linker script is used which is `STM32F429ZITX_FLASH.ld` . Do STM32CubeIDE use one or two linker scripts to build the project? If it uses only one, then why did it generate two linker scripts?

Below, I've posted the build log. Here's the piece of command I found in the build log:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "STM32F429ZI-Test.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/home/biomed/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.4.0/STM32F429ZI-Test/STM32F429ZITX_FLASH.ld"
```

[image: Project Explorer]

arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "STM32F429ZI-Test.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/home/biomed/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.4.0/STM32F429ZI-Test/STM32F429ZITX_FLASH.ld"

```
14:10:36 **** Build of configuration Debug for project STM32F429ZI-Test ****
make -j8 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -g3 -c -x assembler-with-cpp -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Startup/startup_stm32f429zitx.d" -MT"Core/Startup/startup_stm32f429zitx.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Startup/startup_stm32f429zitx.o" "../Core/Startup/startup_stm32f429zitx.s"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/main.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/main.d" -MT"Core/Src/main.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/main.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.d" -MT"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.d" -MT"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/syscalls.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/syscalls.d" -MT"Core/Src/syscalls.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/syscalls.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/sysmem.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/sysmem.d" -MT"Core/Src/sysmem.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/sysmem.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.d" -MT"Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "STM32F429ZI-Test.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/home/biomed/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.4.0/STM32F429ZI-Test/STM32F429ZITX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="STM32F429ZI-Test.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
Finished building target: STM32F429ZI-Test.elf
 
arm-none-eabi-size   STM32F429ZI-Test.elf 
arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S  STM32F429ZI-Test.elf  > "STM32F429ZI-Test.list"
arm-none-eabi-objcopy  -O binary  STM32F429ZI-Test.elf  "STM32F429ZI-Test.bin"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   4672      20    1572    6264    1878 STM32F429ZI-Test.elf
Finished building: default.size.stdout
 
Finished building: STM32F429ZI-Test.bin
 
Finished building: STM32F429ZI-Test.list
 

14:10:39 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.744ms)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do STM32CubeIDE use one or two linker scripts to build the project?

One.

> Why are there 2 generated linker scripts by STM32CubeIDE?
> If it uses only one, then why did it generate two linker scripts?

If you would want to execute (mostly for debugging) a program from RAM, you could use the second linker script, that places `.data` in RAM only. CubeMX generates two, linker scripts so that you can use the second one if you have the need to.